# Input Problems Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, sublimetext3

I am very new to programming and was trying to mess around with inputs. I wrote a simple birthday calculator a few weeks ago:

```
    name = " # name"
bday = # year of birth
current_year = 2020

age = current_year - bday

print(name.title() + " will turn:")
print(age)
print("this year")
```

I decided to improve on this concept by using actual input and started messing around in Sublime. it allows me to input the name, but when i press enter, nothing happens.

Here is the input version of the program:

```
current_year = 2020
name = str(input("what is the name: "))
bday = str(input("what year were they born in: "))

age = current_year - bday

print(name.title() + " will turn:")
print(age)
print("this year")
```

Comment: Don't use str function with input function

Comment: It still isn’t working :\

Comment: `current_year` as an int, while `bday` is a string- hence subtraction ain't gonna work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your code again when you asks the user to enter the bday then you convert it in str. So except str() use int ().